# Groovy: GroupBy and get object with max date

Tags: groovy

How can I get a new list from a list of objects, grouped by a field `ts` and with max `startDate`?

```groovy
def list = [
  new Timeserie(ts:11, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:04:36')),
  new Timeserie(ts:11, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:14:36')),
  new Timeserie(ts:12, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:24:36')),
  new Timeserie(ts:12, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:34:36')),
]

list.each{ println it }             
def byTs = list.groupBy({ tss -> tss.ts })          
println "byTs Size: " + byTs.size()
```

Expected results:

```
[new Timeserie(ts:11, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:14:36'),
new Timeserie(ts:12, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:34:36'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 operations you can chain to get expected result:

- `groupBy { it.ts }` to create a map where key is `ts` and value is a list of timeseries `Map<Integer, List<Timeserie>>`
- `collectEntries { [(it.key): it.value.max { it.startDate }] }` to convert `Map<Integer, List<Timeserie>>` to `Map<Integer, Timeserie>` where mapped object is a time series with highest `startDate`
- `values()` to get `Collection<Timeserie>` from `Map<Integer, Timeserie>`

A full example looks like this:

```
def list = [
  new Timeserie(ts:11, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:04:36')),
  new Timeserie(ts:11, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:14:36')),
  new Timeserie(ts:12, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:24:36')),
  new Timeserie(ts:12, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:34:36')),
]

def result =  list.groupBy { it.ts }
  .collectEntries { [(it.key): it.value.max { it.startDate }] }
  .values()

println result
```

Output:

```
[Timeserie(11, Mon Feb 12 20:14:36 CET 2018), Timeserie(12, Mon Feb 12 20:34:36 CET 2018)]
```

Comment: Thx! dziekuje :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `withDefault()` to do the trick:

```
def list = [  [ts:11, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:04:36')],   [ts:11, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:14:36')],  [ts:12, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:24:36')],  [ts:12, startDate:new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', '2018-02-12 20:34:36')], ]

def res = list.inject( [:].withDefault{ [ ts:null, startDate:new Date( 0 ) ] } ){ res, ts ->
  res[ ts.ts ].ts = ts.ts
  res[ ts.ts ].startDate = new Date( Math.max( ts.startDate.time, res[ ts.ts ].startDate.time ) )
  res
}.values()

assert '[[ts:11, startDate:Mon Feb 12 20:14:36 UTC 2018], [ts:12, startDate:Mon Feb 12 20:34:36 UTC 2018]]' == res.toString()
```

Note: I replaced the `Timeserie` class with a `Map` for simplicity sake